# Worldbuilding is getting some very negative concerning questions (questionable legality)

Tags: discussion

Multiple times recently, I have seen questions on Worldbuilding which I have been concerned about. Many of them could easily be masked attempts at asking for advice for criminal activity. One such recent question was about how to get yourself alone with the president; that one I can see being legite but it still caused me to raise an eyebrow.

The most recent example of this is the most blatant so far: [How can I build a nuclear reactor in my backyard?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/76274/how-can-i-build-a-nuclear-reactor-in-my-backyard)

I can completely understand having a story where your average Joe has their own nuclear reactor. That is fine. Having a story with nuclear reactors does not require a question like this.

There are a lot of very smart people on here answering questions. I fear that if you are not careful, worldbuilding could be a place where people secretly scheme some bad stuff with unknowing helpers.

Should questions that could be used for nefarious purposes be off-topic? I'm not saying they definitely should be, but I am leaning toward yes. If you go to a chemistry stack exchange and ask "What chemicals do I need to make the cheapest IED?" as opposed to asking about some specific chemicals and their properties; you'll likely get deleted and reported to authorities. I suppose the metric should be something like "Are these questions more like asking for an IED or more like asking an innocent question about chemicals which just coincidentally happen to be used in explosives among other things?"

Other posts which I thought odd were ones about breaking and entering, stealing, assassinating, etc. in various fantasy settings, for which answers were often like "Your setting doesn't really change the basic facts, so you would do it just like you would in real life, and here is the best way to do it for real..." But this one about nuclear reactors seems even less reasonable than those.

Comment: There has already been a discussion about this topic. You can find it here at the discussion [Should we be midnful of potentially dangerous questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/should-we-be-mindful-of-potentially-dangerous-questions)

Comment: @Secespitus Thank you. There is not much discussion on that, but yes, that is just about the same question. I would request, however, that this not be closed as a duplicate (at least *yet*) unless people are going to discuss more on that other question, which might not be likely.

Comment: I suppose, as long as the answers do not provide too much and stay within the realm of fantasy, then perhaps it is not off topic. But if someone puts up an answer explaining processes and engineering for uranium refinement, I would delete it hard with the giant ban-hammer.

Comment: You can always add an answer to the other question to raise awareness of the topic. I think it's very good that you are going to Meta because of this. When you write an answer to the other post it will be on the top of the active tab and regular users of the Meta will surely see your post. Leaving this open if it is the same question is against the rules of StackExchange. Duplicated should be marked as such, so that there is one source to search for this topic. Just because the other one has an accepted answer does not mean we can't discuss more on that post.

Comment: @Secespitus Question: If I click the "That solved my question!" button on the "This question already has an answer" banner, will that close the question? If yes, I might try editing the question enough to make it not a duplicate. It is a discussion, after all.

Comment: @Secespitus Ok, thank you.

Comment: I don't know about that banner. If you edit this question so that it is not a duplicate it will of course stay open, as it is a different question. It can also be reopened after some edits.

Comment: Mix equal parts <household cleaner #1> and <household disinfectant>.  Add a small amount of <household cleaner #2> as a catalyst.  Refrigerate for <time>.  Extract the resulting precipitate by running through a coffee filter, then rinse with <household cleaner #1> and let dry.  There you go: a cheap IED.  Just hope it doesn't blow up in your face.

Comment: @Mark: Remember that you have to get <household disinfectant> up to about ten times the concentration it's sold at before you mix it with <household cleaner #1>; also, you don't actually need to refrigerate the mix, as long as you're careful not to use too much of <household cleaner #1>, and the reaction finishes up quicker at room temperature.  (I still wouldn't recommend this recipe anyways; it's far too touchy.)