# Would a question about how deep someone needs to be buried so they wouldn't be found be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

My friend has just heard about StackExchange and is in the middle of writing a horror story. When I showed her this site she asked me:

"Could I ask how deep you would have to bury someone so they wouldn't be found?"

This got me thinking: is this on-topic?

Answer (score 8):

#### If your friend puts in enough details this could be on-topic

The problem is that there are many possible scenarios that you have to think of. For example: are we talking about the police having only got an anonymous tip that they should search an area the size of a house? Or are talking about an area of a graveyard? What resources does the esearching party have? Just humans? Specially trained dogs? Are we talking about a current-day setting? Or for example near-future? Is there a time limit involved? "Never" is quite a lot harder than "it's not reasonable a body will be found in the span of a couple years".

There are lots of questions that your friend would have to answer. In theory it could be on-topic, but it could just as well be off-topic. For example a simple "How deep you would have to bury someone so they wouldn't be found?" is lacking details and therefore seems to be *too broad* for me. I recommend that your friend writes a draft and you put it in the [Sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4835/sandbox-for-proposed-questions). The problem is that you need 5 reputation minimum to post on Meta, so your friend won't be able to post it here, unless she first asks/answers/edits something on the Main Site.

A little warning though about this specific topic: there are quite a few people who don't like gruesome topics. Look at the [torture](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/torture) tag for example. Depending on how the question is posed you might need to expect a higher chance that someone will downvote such a question. Again, the Sandbox can help with finding a way to phrase such a question.

See also: [Should we be mindful of potentially dangerous questions?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1978/28789) and [Should questions about painfully killing people be welcomed on this site?](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/should-questions-about-painfully-killing-people-be-welcomed-on-this-site?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: There are currently 12 questions with that tag but 10 of those from the same author???

Comment: @JanDoggen Yes... that user likes this very specific topic...

Answer (score 2):

If your writer friend is actually ["constructing an imaginary world"](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour), then questions about making that world would certainly be on topic! And she would be most welcome to join us and ask any & all worldbuilding questions she cares to ask!

Even if she's not actually building an imaginary world, I suspect SE would still be a good resource. There is, after all, [**Writing Stack Exchange**](https://writing.stackexchange.com) which be a more appropriate forum for her specific question.